# How to detect the current input language?

Tags: c++, mobile, symbian, s60

I am looking for a working code snippet for Symbian S60 5th edition in which:

a) an application can detect the current input language (not the UI language);

b) an application can receive notifications when current input language is changed.

The function `CurrentLanguage()` from `CPtiEngine` always returns `NULL`, so that does not seem to be an option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the answer on my own. Here is the code:

CAknSettingCache& cache = CAknEnv::Static()->SettingCache();

TLanguage lang = cache.InputLanguage();

Answer (score 1):

Open the SDK docs ( or http://library.forum.nokia.com ) and search for "PTI Engine API" or CPtiEngine.

Comment: The function CurrentLanguage from the PtiEngine API does not work.